# Finding video playback speed of a video streaming in mobile app

Tags: video, video-streaming, appium

could someone help me with this.
I have a mobile app (android) which streams videos. I want to find the speed at which each video is buffered in the app. Any suggestions on how to achieve this using appium?

Answer (score 0):

Appium is a tool to automate user-like e2e scenarios, mostly UI interactions. It has no functionality/API to access the process of buffering stream in the app.

To achive your goal I believe you need to write a test on a lower level: in your app source code.